# How to use a QTimer in a separate QThread

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt5, qthread, qtimer

I have some computationally heavy task that I want to run in a loop after every 5 seconds without blocking the main event-loop. For this, I intend to use a `QTimer` and a separate thread to run it. I have tried the following code but it has not worked so far:

```
@pyqtSlot()
def heavy_task_function():
    # Sleep for 10 seconds to simulate heavy computation
    time.sleep(10)
    print "First Timer Fired"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QCoreApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    threaded_timer = ModbusComThread(heavy_task_function)
    threaded_timer.start()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Where:

```
class ModbusComThread(QThread):

    def __init__(self, slot_function):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.slot_function = slot_function
        self.send_data_timer = None

    def run(self):
        print "Timer started on different thread"
        self.send_data_timer = QTimer(self)
        self.send_data_timer.timeout.connect(self.slot_function)
        self.send_data_timer.start(5000)

    def stop(self):
        self.send_data_timer.stop()
```

The `slot_function` is never fired by the `QTimer` in `threaded_timer`. Is my threading architecture correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `QTimer` needs a running event-loop. By default, `QThread.run()` will start a local event-loop for the thread, but if you completely override it in the way that you have done, that won't happen - so the timer events will never be processed.

In general, when you need a local event-loop you should create a worker object to do all the processing and then use [moveToThread](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread) to put it in a separate thread. If not, it's perfectly okay to override `QThread.run()`.

The demo below shows how to do this. Note that it's very important to create the timer *after the thread has started*, otherwise it would be created in the wrong thread and its timer-events wouldn't be processed by the thread's event-loop. It's also important that all communication between the worker thread and the main thread is done via signals, so as to ensure thread-safety. Never try to directly perform GUI operations outside the main thread, as Qt does not support that at all. For the purposes of the demo, a second timer in the main thread is used to stop all processing after a fixed interval. If there was a GUI, user intervention via a button would achieve the same thing.

**Demo**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class ModbusComWorker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def start(self):
        self._timer = QTimer(self)
        self._timer.timeout.connect(self.process)
        self._timer.start(2000)

    def stop(self):
        self._timer.stop()
        self.finished.emit()

    def process(self):
        print('processing (thread: %r)' % QThread.currentThread())
        QThread.sleep(3)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QCoreApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    thread = QThread()
    worker = ModbusComWorker()
    worker.moveToThread(thread)

    def finish():
        print('shutting down...')
        thread.quit()
        thread.wait()
        app.quit()
        print('stopped')

    worker.finished.connect(finish)
    thread.started.connect(worker.start)
    thread.start()

    timer = QTimer()
    timer.setSingleShot(True)
    timer.timeout.connect(worker.stop)
    timer.start(15000)

    print('starting (thread: %r)' % QThread.currentThread())

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Output**:

```
starting (thread: <PyQt5.QtCore.QThread object at 0x7f980d096b98>)
processing (thread: <PyQt5.QtCore.QThread object at 0x7f980d0968a0>)
processing (thread: <PyQt5.QtCore.QThread object at 0x7f980d0968a0>)
processing (thread: <PyQt5.QtCore.QThread object at 0x7f980d0968a0>)
processing (thread: <PyQt5.QtCore.QThread object at 0x7f980d0968a0>)
processing (thread: <PyQt5.QtCore.QThread object at 0x7f980d0968a0>)
shutting down...
stopped
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer!